# App with Workflow 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, app

I added a Workflow in my SharePoint-hosted App. But the Workflow is not deployed correctly. After looking into the Feature of the App, I realized the Workflow is not included into it. Also the Scope of the Feature is Web only. And you can't change the scope.

How is it possible to add a Workflow to Apps, if you can't get it included into the Features?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Move Workflow from Items in Solution to Items in Feature and then deploy the app.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I need to drag and drop the Workflow from the solution to the folder of the feature? If yes, this doesn't work. I can't drop it into the folder

Comment: If you mean, that I need to put the Workflow in the Feature from the left list to the right one, the Workflow is not listed as possible item.

Comment: No, when you double click on a feature, You will see two sections 1. Items in Solution and 2. Items in feature. In between you will find buttons which help moving items between two sections

Comment: Yeah, I just realized what you meant. But it's not listed in Items in Solution. :(

Comment: I added a Screenshot for you to verify

Comment: Have you got workflow Manager installed?

Comment: Yes. Installed and running.

Answer (score 0):

1) create your app project in vs2012

2) add workflow to app project

3) make it a site workflow

those are the simple steps to add a workflow to a sharepoint 2013 app, it would be recommended to use vs2012 if your not! the workflow shouldnt be within the feature but within the app project!

full tut here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/09/18/step-by-step-sending-email-messages-from-a-workflow-in-an-app-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

**EDIT**

workflows are not added to the feature folder within vs2012!!!! they are added within the project like below:

[image]

its linked to the project that is linked to the feature, you can add a .cs class to the feature that overrieds the event items but that is it!

follow this link to make sure your correclty creating the app/workflow properly!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456545.aspx

Comment: I've done all this stuff. But the Workflow is not listed in the feature.

Comment: when you say its not listed in the feature do you mean within visual studios project or within sharepoint?

Comment: As shown in my Screenshot. In Visual Studio it's not listed in the Feature list. Also, because of this, it's not deployed on SharePoint

Comment: just updated my answer